# Multiple inheritance in python vs c++

Tags: c++, python, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

This is a Python and C++ question.

I am experimenting with multiple inhertiance and I came across this example.

```
B1 B2
 \ /
  D
```

Say I have two (independent?) parent classes `B1, B2` and one child class `D`. We're only interested in objects of `class D`.

```
class B1:
    def f1(self):
        print "In f1"

class B2:
    def f2(self):
        self.f1()

class D (B1, B2):
    def fD(self):
        self.f2()

d = D()
d.fD()

Output: In f1
```

What's interesting (at least to me) is that `class B2` has no knowledge about `class B1` and yet `f2` can call `self.f1()` with no problems.

I tried to replicate this exact thing in C++ and I couldn't make it work because I don't know how to call `f1` from `f2`.

```
class B1 {
    public:
    virtual ~B1() {}
    virtual void f1() { cout << "In f1" << endl; }
};

class B2 {
    public:
    virtual ~B2() {}
    virtual void f2() { /* What goes here?? */ }
};

class D : public B1, public B2 {
    public:
    void fD() { f2(); }
};
```

So, I want to know how/why Python can handle this but C++ cannot?

Also, what minimal changes can we make to the C++ code to make it behave like the Python code?

Comment: It's not very interesting in Python. It just tries to (dynamically) resolve the given property through a MRO (Method Resolution Order) tree (it's a bit more complicated than just looking for a property thanks to all the different rules, but it's about how it can be summed up). The tree MR (Method Resolution) *always* starts from the receiver which is the current object instance when self is used - this is also how Python allows overriding and polymorphism - and not the defining type of the method. To call a method on a particular type, see `TheType.method(self, ..)`

Comment: @user2246674: Is that true when the classes are not "new style" (i.e. derived from `object`)?  If that's important then the answer should be edited.

Comment: Seems like I am quite late here....this can be done using "Type Traits" (C++ template programming concept).
Idea is class B2 can either derive from a TypeTrait or contain a Templated Class as a param. The constructor of D can pass itself to set the instance variable and method f1 will be called on that.

Answer (score 1):

> what minimal changes can we make to the C++ code to make it behave like the Python code?

**Short answer:**  You can't.  `B2` has no idea that it's going to form part of a sub-class that also has `B1` as super-class.

**Long answer:** You can, if you use some grotty downcasting (essentially casting `this` to a `D*`).  But it's probably not a good idea, as `*this` is not necessarily a `D`.

Answer (score 1):

This works in python because the name `f1` in class `B2` is being resolved at runtime.  This is "duck typing" -- the object reference in `self` just has to have a valid `f1` to call, which it does when you construct it that way.

The most C++-like way to get similar behavior in C++ is the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).  Your C++ version of `B2` needs to know what it is a part of.  Making it a template of its derived type gives you a "clean" way to do the `dynamic_cast` that others have suggested.  It's cleaner because there will be a new class `B2<T>` for every class that derives from it.  Each specialization will have a distinct `f2` which uses the right cast to get to the right `f1`.  It will work much like the python version in that the existence of a callable `f1` is all that is required (at compile time rather than runtime, though).

```
class B1 {
    public:
    virtual ~B1() {}
    virtual void f1() { cout << "In f1" << endl; }
};

template <typename Derived>
class B2 {
    public:
    virtual ~B2() {}
    virtual void f2() { dynamic_cast<Derived *>(this)->f1(); }
};

class D : public B1, public B2<D> {
    public:
    void fD() { f2(); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how/why Python can handle this but C++ cannot?

That's because Python is dynamically typed and C++ is statically typed.

> what minimal changes can we make to the C++ code to make it behave like the Python code?

If you want to program in Python you know where to find it. Programming in C++ using Python ways is counter-idiomatic and is generally frowned upon. That said, if you want to do it anyway, you use `dynamic_cast<B2*>(this)`.